# How to change the url in router when people directly click the routers?

Tags: knockout.js, router, single-page-application, durandal

I am developing a SPA website with durandal.
Here is my router's config:

```
var routes = [{
    url: 'profile',
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/profile',
    name: 'Profile',
    visible: true
}, {
    url: 'batchOverview',
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/batchOverview',
    name: 'Batche Overview',
    visible: true
}, {
    url: 'batch',
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/batch',
    name: 'Batche Detail',
    visible: true
}, {
    url: 'page',
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/page',
    name: 'Page',
    visible: true
}];
```

When people click the routers directly, the url in the address bar is like this:

```
http://localhost:7778/#/batch
```

What I want is that I can add paramenters to the url when people click the routers directly.
The url may look like this:

```
http://localhost:7778/#/batch?pId=Gridsum&batchId=3
```

Now I can use router.navigateTo(url) to make it when people click a custom button. But I need to make it when people click the router directly and change the paramenters dynamically.

I don't know whether it will be OK if I set an observable in router.map(). But I don't think it is a good way.Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: When you say : "When I click the routers directly" you mean when the user click on a link ?

Comment: @Damien Yes. Sorry I'll correct it.

Comment: So why don't you set the href's link with this url ?
http://localhost:7778/#/batch?pId=Gridsum&batchId=3

Comment: @Damien Well, the paramenters' values in the url is dynamic. I need to know where could I send the paramenters to. If there is a way to config the url of routers after a router is activated, it will help a lot.

Comment: You could add 2 routes for the same page :
/#/batch and /#/batch?pId=:pID&batchId=:bID

Comment: @Damien The problem is not the paramenters but the value. For example, at a page I need /#/batch?pId=xx and at another page I need /#/batch?pId=yy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an observable property on the main view model, that contains the batch url (with parameters).
Bind this url to the link of your menu. 
By doing that you will need to create a new route with the parameters. eg :
/#/batch?pId=:pID&batchId=:bID

Durandal routing is based on SammyJS. So if you need more information routes parameters please take a look at : [SammyJS routes](http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Finally I got this: router.visibleRoutes()[1].hash = '#/batchOverview?pId=' + encodeURIComponent(vm.profiles()[xx].Id()); which can let me modify the router's url anywhere. Sorry I forgot to say I use the hash attr in the nav.html.